# How to change base url of backend in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I have path let path = `"/";`

When it call this path Angular makes path like:

```
http://localhost:4200/backend/api
```

But I need

```
http://localhost/backend/api
```

Without port, ho to set this option in Angular?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the best use is to set a base url in your enviromenmt.ts file.
a nice article about enviorment files
environment.ts file:

for example:

```
environment.ts file:

export const environment = {
    DefaultLanguage: "en",
    production: false,
    development: true,
    environmentName:"DEV",
    baseURL:"http://localhost/backend/api"    
};

environment.prod.ts:

export const environment = {
    DefaultLanguage: "en",
    production: true,
    development: false,
    environmentName:"PROD",
    baseURL:''
};
```

and then you can apply some logic as:

```
if (environment.development) {
    this.baseURL = environment.baseURL;
} else if(environment.baseUrl && environment.baseUrl != '') {
    this.baseURL = environment.baseUrl + "/api/";
} else {
    this.baseURL = location.origin + "/api/";
}
```

and make sure you have the following configuration on angular.json file:

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [{
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }]
    }
}
```

This is the same for QA or UAT environments as well. See the picture below:

[image]

you can create multiple environments with different url hard-coded or logic based urls.

So let's reflect this change to `package.json` file:

[image]

Run `npm run build:prod` for:

```
`build:prod`: `ng build --configuration=production`
```

Run `npm run build:dev` for:

```
`build:dev`: `ng build --configuration=development`
```

Run `npm run build:uat` for:

```
`build:uat`: `ng build --configuration=uat`
```

Run `npm run build:qa` for:

```
`build:qa`: `ng build --configuration=qa`
```

Comment: To use `baseURL:null`?

Comment: I think I have to use proxy settings

Comment: @you should apply your custom project at the service contractor. 
as I did.
make sure that your environment.ts  (which is the development one) baseurl is your wanted base url and apply the logic at the constractor

Answer (score 1):

When you set your path as "/". It means scheme, host and port from your current window location. So if your window location is "http://localhost:4200/somePage", you will expect "http://localhost:4200" will be the baseURL.
If you have made a reverse proxy of 80 to your backend. You should declare it as an independent, fully qualified url. For e.g.

```
const baseUrl = "http://localhost"
```